# What happens if I mistakenly push a local branch to master

Tags: git

I made a mistake just now by mistakenly issued the command:

```
   git push origin master
```

on a local branch, say, mybranch. This branch is branched from master and contains some local changes that master does not have.

The message I get is:

```
   Everything up-to-date
```

I checked the master log there is nothing abnormal. My question is that:

1. Did I mess master branch?
2. Why does it says "Everything up-to-date" even if mybranch contains something that master does not have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't specify the source(local) and destination(remote) branches, `push` uses the specified spec as both source and destination. So, basically, when you did

```
git push origin master
```

you just pushed your local master branch to the remote master branch.

To actually push your branch into master you should do

```
git push origin mybranch:master
```

Comment: So you mean the "git push origin master" command I executed actually tried to push my local master to the remote master EVEN IF my current branch was mybranch?

Comment: Yup, that's how the command works. If you don't specify the refspec, it uses the current branch as source and destination, if you specify one refspec, it uses that instead, and finally you can use <src>:<dest> to fully identify from where to where the push should be.

Comment: You can always `git diff origin/master` to check.

Comment: Or `git log origin/master` as well.